# ggplot2 stacked bar chart with total proportions for the heights of bars and fill as proportion of each species

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-bar-chart

This code makes a bar plot that displays the proportion of fish with ingested microplastics across several 5-year bins. I also want it to display the proportion of each species by stacking different colors. My problem with the plot produced with this code is that it adds up the proportions of microplastics when there are more than one species in the time bin. I want the height of the bar to be the total proportion of fish in that time bin that have microplastics. For example in 2010-2014, 27% of the fish had ingested plastic (which should be the height of the bar), but it appears as 81% because Diaphus theta has 27%, Tarletonbeania crenularis has 26% and Stenobrachius leucopsarus has 27% and it sums those to get the height.

```
bin_prop <- tsdata %>%
  group_by(Year_Bin, Species) %>%
  summarize(Proportion = mean(MPs))

ggplot(bin_prop, aes(fill = Species, y = Proportion, x = Year_Bin)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = custom_colors) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  labs(fill = "Species") +
  xlab("Years") +
  ylab("Proportion of Myctophids with Microparticles") +
  ggtitle("Microparticle Concentration Over Time")+
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0, 1),
    breaks = seq(0, 1, by = 0.2)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1))
```

I know it is probably something small that I am not including in the code - any help with this would be great, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data shared using `dput()`. It will also help if you clarify what the variable `MPs` reflects. Is this a count? Is this a percentage share?